# Black screen after login in

Tags: xorg

I've done a stupid thing with my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

I wanted to write in Chinese, so I've followed the instructions in a link to install gcin, which is supposed to give me access to Chinese input. Big error, it didn't work at all, text editor was unusable, and gcin menus were in traditional Chinese. Worst decision ever.

So I did `apt-get autoremove gcin` to get rid of that horrible packet. And I rebooted my computer. Now, I can see login screen, I can type my password, and I have a black screen with nothing.

Please note that I was able to check that I'm typing my password with English input corresponding to my keyboard layout. Xorg is broken somehow, and I don't know how to fix that.

Two things to take into account:

1. Before restarting my computer, I have proceeded to an update with the update manager, and it has upgraded Mono, which is a big thing that I don't know too much about it, so my problem could from that also.
2. When I have installed gcin, I did a stupid thing. There were 2 choices, either to change a user config file (I chose that option unfortunately, even if it was marked as a non recommended option) or not touch user config file.

So I'm stuck with that black screen, and don't know what to do...  The only thing I was able to do was to open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I just had to install anew gcin via terminal. 
Then it gave me access to that graphically buggy ubuntu.

Then I went to Settings > Region & Language > Manage Install Languages

At bottom of new window, select IBus for Keyboard input method system.

Restart

And then get rid of that stupid gcin

Enjoy